# Change text content globally on Google Fonts

Tags: google-fonts

On the old Google Fonts website we used to be able to change the text content for all the fonts using an input field at the top of the page.

With the new [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) website, the text content is changed on an individual basis by clicking/selecting the text itself.

Is there a way to change the text content globally (for *all* fonts) using the new website? If I want to compare a word across multiple fonts, I now have to update the text content for every font I want to compare.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the text for one font. As soon as you do you'll see the option APPLY TO ALL FONTS appear underneath the changed text

Comment: Now that's what I call good design! /s

Comment: This only seems to work on a desktop viewport... mobile does not display the "APPLY TO ALL FONTS" feature.